# invalidate servet session on window blur and mouse activity

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, session, servlets

I hava following jsp code (with javascript). After user logged in, they are able to view this page. When the window goes blur or mouse was inactive for several minutes, I want to redirect page to Google and also let login servlet invalidate current session as well. Current code would only redirect to Goole, but session has not been invalidated right?

How can I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
Test
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastX, lastY = 0;
    var act_timeout = null;
    function doAction() {
        window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")
        <% SOME CODE TO LET SERVLET INVALIDATE CURRENT SESSION ????%>
        return false;
    }
    function move( e ) {
        if( e.clientY == lastY && e.clientX == lastX ) {
            act_timeout = setTimeout( doAction, 5000 );
            return;
        }
        lastX = e.clientX;
        lastY = e.clientY;
        act_timeout = clearTimeout( act_timeout );
    }
    window.onmousemove = move;
    window.onblur = doAction;
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a server-side call first to invalidate the session, then redirect to Google. The server-side part can be implemented with a logout servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet("/logout")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

In your javascript code you only need to replace this line:

```
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")
```

with this one, in order to call the servlet:

```
window.location.assign("/logout")
```

The servlet will take care of the redirect to Google.